# AngularJS 1.7.9 Binding variable from controller to component provide undefined value

Tags: angularjs, binding, components

i'm asking for your help.
I'm an AngularJS begginer and components bindings looks like esotherical for me.
I don't really understand why my variables a sets to undefined.

Could you help me please ?

Here is my HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="mapController as map" style="text-align:center;">
    <div>{{map.lastClickedCountry}}</div>
    <risk-map lastClickedCountry="map.lastClickedCountry"
              countriesUnits="map.countriesUnits">
    </risk-map>
</div>
```

My Component JS :

```
angular.module('riskApp').component("riskMap", {
    bindings: {
        lastClickedCountry: '=',
        countriesUnits: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'template/risk.html',
    controller: function ($scope) {
        this.$onInit = function () {
            console.log("onInit")
            console.log(this);
            console.log($scope);
        };

        this.$onChanges = function () {
            console.log("onChange")
            console.log(this);
            console.log($scope);
        };

        this.setArrivant = function (pays, nombreArrivant) {
            this.countriesUnits[pays].arrivant = nombreArrivant
        }

        this.setStationnaire = function (pays, nombreStationnaire) {
            this.countriesUnits[pays].stationnaire = nombreStationnaire
        }


        this.getArrivant = function (pays) {
            return this.countriesUnits[pays].arrivant
        }

        this.getStationnaire = function (pays) {
            return this.countriesUnits[pays].stationnaire
        }

        this.click = function (country) {
            console.log("Dernier pays : " + this.lastClickedCountry)
            console.log("Pays click : " + country)
            console.log(this)
            this.lastClickedCountry = country;
        }
    }
})
```

My Controller JS:

```
angular.module('riskApp').controller('mapController', function 
CountCtrl($scope) {
    this.lastClickedCountry = "test";
    this.countriesUnits = {}
})
```

Comment: There is a syntax error here: `this.countriesUnits = {);`

Comment: Syntax error fixed, by still the same bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes bindings need to be in [kebab-case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Special_case_styles):

```
<div ng-controller="mapController as map" style="text-align:center;">
    <div>{{map.lastClickedCountry}}</div>
    <risk-map last-clicked-country="map.lastClickedCountry"
              countries-units="map.countriesUnits">
    </risk-map>
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Directive Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)